# Yii 2. Подзапрос в join. '=' вместо 'in'

Tags: yii2

Запрос следующего вида:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `tasks` as t LEFT JOIN 
     `task2status` as t2s ON t2s.id = (SELECT t2s1.id 
                                       FROM task2status as t2s1 
                                       WHERE t2s1.task_id = t.id 
                                       ORDER BY t2s1.id  DESC LIMIT 1)
```

В search модели запрос выглядит так:

```
$query = Tasks::find()->alias('t');
$subQuery = Task2status::find()->alias('t2s')
                               ->select('t2s.id')
                               ->where(['t2s.task_id' => 'tasks.id'])
                               ->orderBy('t2s.id desc')
                               ->limit(1)
                               ->offset(0);
$query->InnerJoin('task2status ts', ['ts.id' => $subQuery]);
```

В результате получаю :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM `tasks` `t` INNER JOIN 
     `task2status` `ts` ON `ts`.`id` IN (SELECT `t2s`.`id` 
                                         FROM `task2status` `t2s` 
                                         WHERE `t2s`.`task_id`='tasks.id' 
                                         ORDER BY `t2s`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1)
```

Необходимо из subselect'а вернуть лишь 1 запись, поэтому и использован `limit`. 
 Yii2 подставляет `in` вместо равенства, а `limit` при `in` нельзя использовать. Но с одной стороны это и понятно, если учесть что я ему передаю. Но а как иначе? Как быть?

Comment: А что если использовать `$db->createCommand();` и выполнять запрос именно так, как нужно вам. :)

Comment: id in (3) и id=3 это ведь эквивалент. Нет?